# MongoDB - $push if array length < n, while update_one

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

That's a small part of my update query using pymongo in python. I want to `$push` ip variable to an array only if its length is less than 10. I know that I can solve this problem firstly finding this user (`find_one`) and checking array's length but it's not an efficient solution. How to handle this problem using mongo?

I read that `$cond` works only in aggregation so I can't figure anything else.

Part of my script:

```
self.db[coll_name].update_one(
             {
                 'summary.userId': user_id
             },
             {'$push':
                 {
                     'summary.ip': ip
                 },
             }
             upsert=True
        )
```

What my brain wants to do:

```
self.db[coll_name].update_one(
             {
                 'summary.userId': user_id
             },
             {
                 "$cond": {"if": {"$size": {"$summary.ip": {"$ne": 10}}},
                         "then": {"$push": ip},
                         "else": pass
             }},
             upsert=True
        )
```

I'm trying to limit myself to pymongo but answers using MongoDB with JS are more than welcome.

EDIT: Sorry for the inconvenience.

I want to be able to update other fields event if the condition wasn't met.

```
self.db[coll_name].update_one(
                 {
                     'summary.userId': user_id
                 },
                 {'$push':
                     {
                         'summary.ip': ip
                     },

                 '$addToSet':
                     {
                         'summary.something_list': something
                     },
                 }
                 upsert=True
            )
```

If I filter by the length of ip array, I won't add `something` if ip list eq 9, which I have to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the filter passed to `Collections.update_one`, you can filter where an ip index of 9 doesn't exist in the collection.

```
filter_ = {
    'summary.userId': user_id,
    'summary.ip.9': {
        '$exists': False
    }
}
update =  {
    '$push': {
        'summary.ip': ip 
    }
}
self.db[coll_name].update_one(filter_, update, upsert=True)
```

Comment: There're two arrays in my document and I wanted to check both of them. I can't imagine a situation where your solution works for this case, but you answered my question and that will do the job for now. Thanks.

Additionally, I wanted to check if len(array_1) > 10: pass and if len(array_2) > 10: pass, so there's a case when I'll be adding only to one of them.

Comment: You can add the second array to the filter just like the first

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I updated my question. If I filter by ip I won't be able to execute the rest of the update query, and there's a lot more. Added an example to my question.

Comment: You may want to separate the query for updating ip field from the query for updating the other fields.

Comment: Yes, that's the best solution I can think of but I was wondering if there's a more efficient way. I wanted to perform only one update_one per document (a user here).

Answer (score 0):

```
var limit =10;
var query = {};
query["arrayName."+limit]={$exists:false}
model.update(query,{$push:{arrayName:value}})
```

the second option I prefer is to have a length field in model and increment or decrement it in push or pull respectively({$push:{arrayName:val},$inc:{length:1}}  or {$pull:{arrayName:val},$inc:{length:-1}}) so you can query simply like

```
model.update({length:{$lt:10}},{$push:{arrayName:value}})
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look deeper into it.